# How to list the errors generated while compiling a masm program ? (the command used for it)

Tags: masm, masm32

There are a few errors in the program that i tried to compile in masm. I forgot the command used to list those errors in the command prompt. Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

/Z display errors including line numbers to screen

Comment: Are you adding /debug too ?